# Symfony Throw custom 404 page inside service

Tags: php, symfony

I need to throw an Exception inside service

```
        $isLangExist = $this->em->getRepository('TranslationBundle:Language')->findOneBy(array(
        'locale' => $this->request->getMasterRequest()->getLocale()
    ));
    if (!$isLangExist) {
        throw new createNotFoundException('you are using unavailable langage');
    }
```

but I got this page is not workinc in prod env

how can i show 404 page with createNotFoundException or any another Exception  type

thanks

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your code is not correct. I would expect it to look like this:

```
if (!$isLangExist) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('you are using unavailable langage');
}
```

The method is part of the abstract base controller you can use, but it's not mandatory. What should work in cases where you don't extend this controller is:

```
if (!$isLangExist) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('you are using unavailable langage');
}
```

Your problem goes beyond the above code, because you don't throw the exception inside a controller as I expected. You throw it inside a Twig extension. This exception will interrupt rendering, which is why the error is not converted into a 404 exception and instead is treated as a 500 error. Potentially you will see other 500-errors with your extension whenever one of the queries fails, which is probably not what you want. Addressing this issue likely requires rethinking how you use these global twig variables.

You could try moving the templates that use these variables into separate templates being rendered by a dedicated controller using [sub requests](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/sub-request-internals) or ESI:

```
{{
    render(controller(
        'AppBundle:Global:_listCategories',
        {
            'locale': app.request.attributes.get('_locale')
        }
    ))
}}
```

Another solution might be to set these with `null` or an error-object whenever something fails and then react to these "alternative" results in your template, which is not what I would prefer.

There are probably many other ways to tackle this. The gist is: rendering error are different than http-exceptions thrown by controllers services. You have to ensure that your templates can either be rendered despite these missing/faulty variables or deal with these missing parameters before rendering the templates, e.g. in an event listener.

Comment: Do you have any error messages inside your logs? Can you add the response headers or a screenshot to your question?

Comment: It looks like the exception is causing issues in your Twig-Extension:
> [2018-08-31 12:06:53] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "you are using unavailable langage" at /var/www/server1/src/FrontBundle/Twig/Extension/TwigGlobalsExtension.php line 46
I assume that this raises the exception before your application is properly booted and that is why Symfony will not convert the exception into a 404 error page. Can you maybe post the code from that Extension to help you debug and solve the error?

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. I'm afraid my answer is not very satisfying, but I hope it still helps you.